# Locked out of Windows 7 by uninstalling USB driver

Tags: windows, drivers, accessibility

I uninstalled my USB driver in Windows 7. Now I can't do anything as keyboard and mouse aren't available. Drivers don't appear to be automatically reinstalled.

Remote desktop connection is disabled.

Safe mode doesn't work either - still no drivers.

There is a PS/2 connection but it also doesn't seem to work. Perhaps no drivers as it wasn't used before?

I don't have a recovery disk. I have a Windows 7 installation disk, but I don't appear to have keyboard or mouse when booting from that either (strange).

Keyboard and mouse work fine in the BIOS. Any ideas on how to get them back in Windows 7?

Comment: I don't think you problem belongs to "serverfault" but you could try to connect to your PC via RDP from an different Client...

Comment: Try to boot from the installation disk and to perform recovery procedure.

Comment: If recovery procedure shows recovery points exists, try to revert.